# How can I recode variables in R using conditional statements, while keeping NA values?

Tags: r

Example/made-up data:

Suppose I want to recode so that if a row has 1 under A, then NA under B is recoded to 0. However, if a row has 0 under A, then B under lunch remains NA. The "A variable, however, also has NA values that I don't want to affect B values.

I've been using code like this: `dat[dat$A==1,]$B<-0`
But it keeps returning an

> ```
> error: issuing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
> due to the NA values.
> ```

```
A  B   C  D   
1  NA  0  1    
0  NA  0  NA    
NA  1  1  1
```

Comment: In the example showed, there is no `lunch`, `breakfast` or `dessert`, assuming that `A, B, C, D` are the column names.

Comment: I'm hungry now.  Maybe `within(dat, B <- replace(B, A == 1, 0))` is what you want

Comment: Could you format your question and add the result of head(dat) ? Thks!

Comment: Whoops, just changed the example. My bad for making everyone think of waffles and grits.

Comment: @MCH Your code should be changed to `dat$B[dat$A==1] <- 0`

Answer (score 0):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[A==1 & is.na(B), B:=0][]
```

If you want to set B as `0` for all `1s` in A

```
setDT(df)[A==1, B:=0][]
```

Or a `base R` method would be

```
df$B[with(df, !!A & is.na(B))] <- 0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 0L, NA), B = c(NA, NA, 1L), C = c(0L, 
0L, 1L), D = c(1L, NA, 1L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class =
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```